# In template<class It> function where It is an iterator, can I make It::value_type work for both vector::iterators and array::iterators?

Tags: c++, templates

I have been writing some functions that take a template called `It`, which should be an iterator. Then I use the `It::value_type` for some functionality. This has been working for most containers I have tried but fails for `std::array`. If I do use an `std::array` I get the error

```
error: ‘long unsigned int*’ is not a class, struct, or union type
```

So I see the problem, the iterator for the `std::array` is just a pointer, which makes sense to me. Therefore it has no `::value_type` defined. But how can I make my templated code so that this works for `std::array` and `std::vector`, `std::list` etc?

I made a MWE, the function in it just a silly pathological example that shows my problem

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <class It>
void print_accumulate(It first, It last) {
    typename It::value_type result{};    // What do I write here??
    while (first != last) {
        result += *first;
        ++first;
    }
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::vector<size_t> v = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; /* Replacing with std::array<size_t, 5> gives error */
    print_accumulate(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

The above works just fine for just about every container I've tried, `vector`, `list`, `set` etc. However, when I try to run the code by replacing the `std::vector<size_t>` with `std::array<size_t, 5>`, i get the error message I gave.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`iterator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)

```
template <class It>
void print_accumulate(It first, It last) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type result{};    // use iterator_traits
    while (first != last) {
        result += *first;
        ++first;
    }
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Much obliged :) I will accept your answer once the required waiting time is up. Just out of curiosity, is there every any reason to use It::value_type instead of what you gave?

Comment: @Slugger If you want to write portable and correct iterator logic, then no -- not really. The `iterator_traits` is meant to be portable for all types that may be iterators (including pointers, which can't have member types). If you write `typename It::value_type`, then you're coupling yourself to an implementation of an iterator. This might make sense if you're writing your own container and you know that the type has a `value_type`, but in most cases this reduces generality, portability and correctness

Comment: @Human-Compiler Thanks that makes sense

Comment: To have generic code that will work with arrays and containers use iterator_traits. Traits technique is a technique in C++ to link with non-class types (like pointers) some properties (like value_type). If you know your code will only work with containers - then you can use `It::value_type` - but it is less generic approach.